# Python - Keylogger does not work when launched through psexec

Tags: python, psexec, keylogger

I cannot get a simple keylogger designed in python to work when launched through PSEXEC on a remote computer (I am authorized to use it). The original code can be found on     https://www.thepythoncode.com/article/write-a-keylogger-python. I modified it a little bit to also show the name of window focused and also to write all the output to a single file.

The procedure I currently follow is:

1. Copy compiled version of keylogger to the remote PC.
2. Connect to it through PSEXEC and then launch the copied keylogger.
3. The keylogger should give output in form of a .txt file after 30 seconds, but it does not.
4. Also, it does not show in the launch processes.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Please focus your question, first issue is to verify you can connect remotely, then see if the keylogger executes, then check it output and finally return the content. This can easily be split up into lots of questions.

Comment: Yep I can connect. From what I have seen the keylogger does not show when tasklist is run. Also I can confirm that the keylogger is able to run when launched thorugh GUI.